# why gdb command info thread gives 2 Thread 899 0x00000000 in ?? () in arm

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, arm

I am tring to debug the core dump with gdb .It is working fine with x86 machine(ubuntu 12.04) but i compiled the same source for arm using arm compiler and try to get "info thred".But in the case of x86 machine(ubuntu 12.04),its giving proper result but in the case of arm its not giving thread memory address.I have followed the following steps.

## gdb thread core

gdb>info thread

Where "thread" is binary file name and "core" is the core dump file name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include<string.h>
pthread_t thread;

struct rlimit rl;

void* thread3 (void* d)
{
  int count3 = 0;

  while(count3 < 10){
    printf("Thread 3: %d\n", count3++);
    printf("Thread3: %ld\n",pthread_self());
  }
  return NULL;
}

void* thread2 (void* d)
{
  int count2 = 0;
        char *buff=NULL;
    rl.rlim_cur = 10000000;
    rl.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &rl);

  while(count2 < 10){
    printf("Thread 2: %d\n", count2++);
    printf("Thread2: %ld\n",pthread_self());
  }
        strcpy(buff,"Creating SIGSEGV interrupt for the process");
  return NULL;
}

int main (){

  pthread_create (&thread, NULL, thread2, NULL);
  pthread_create (&thread, NULL, thread3, NULL);
  
  //Thread 1
  int count1 = 0;

  while(count1 < 10){
        printf("Thread 1: %d\n", count1++);
  }

  pthread_join(thread,NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: put `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` while compiling. You may need to tell your toolchain specifics including options.

Comment: I am using arm-linux-gcc for cross compilation for arm.

Comment: that's like saying I'm driving a white car. did you try the no-omit-framepointer ?

Comment: Are you using a **cross-gdb** or the PC `gdb` with the ARM core file?  You need to use a **cross-gdb** configured with the same threading module as your OS.  You must be using Linux?  I don't think a bare metal 'multithreading' ARM gcc exists.

Comment: By working fine on a PC, do you mean the code works fine **OR** it crashes on the PC and you can use a core dump to see where the error is?  `gdb` may not be able to get stack traces if there is a stack corruption.  You may wish to declare separate copies of `thread`.  Ie, `thread2` and `thread3` need to be tracked separately and joined.  I see you are intentionally creating an `SIGSEGV` for thread2?  The main thread and thread3 may complete before thread2 on some platforms.

Comment: I have tried to compile  -fno-omit-frame-pointer option with arm-linux-gcc.Compilation was successful.But the result was same.I am using cross gdb.Yes thread 2 creating SIGSEVV.So i can get core dump.I like to debug core dump by using gdb for arm.